# Destructuring with variant arguments that depend on others, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use destructuring in an interface where a property depends on other one?
My arguments are the following:

```
interface PropsVariationA {
  functionToExecute?: () => void;
  executeExtraFunction: true;
}

interface PropsVariationB {
  executeExtraFunction: false;
}

type Props = PropsVariationA | PropsVariationB;
```

So when I try to use it with destructuring I (obviously) get an error:

```
function SomeFunctionWithDestructuring({
  executeExtraFunction,
  functionToExecute = () => {} // Error: property 'functionToExecute' doesnt exist on type 'Props'
}: Props) {
  if (executeExtraFunction) functionToExecute();
  return null;
}
```

Check out this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-turing-wv5c2).

I managed to make it work without destructuring but I wonder if there is any way.

Comment: I would guess it's not possible. Since with using a default parameter value, you would be trying to access a property that's potentially invalid in one possible variation of Props. `undefined` is the perfect candidate for such variables.

Comment: I'm wondering if [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) could be used here...

Answer (score 0):

If you set functionToExecute to undefined in PropsVariationB then it would work:

```
interface PropsVariationA {
  functionToExecute?: () => void;
  executeExtraFunction: true;
}

interface PropsVariationB {
  functionToExecute: undefined;
  executeExtraFunction: false;
}

type Props = PropsVariationA | PropsVariationB;

// function without destructuring
function SomeFunction(props: Props) {
  if (props.executeExtraFunction && props.functionToExecute)
    props.functionToExecute();
  return "a";
}

// function with destructuring
function SomeFunctionWithDestructuring({
  executeExtraFunction,
  functionToExecute = () => {} // Any way to do destructuing here?
}: Props) {
  if (executeExtraFunction) functionToExecute();
  return null;
}

// This error is right
SomeFunction({ executeExtraFunction: false, functionToExecute: () => {} });
```